# Java library to make recorded phone call

Tags: java

Scenario:  GSM SIM card is connected to PC using a USB port. I have a audio file. I have a list of mobile numbers to call.

Question: I'm looking for JAVA library which detects the GSM SIM card, and allow my application to make a recorded phone call to this list of mobile numbers.

Extra Information: This is NOT A J2ME application. I studied some of resources from net. I found this http://smslib.org/ & http://www.voicent.com/devnet/docs/javaapi.htm which does not completely solve my problem. Former can only send SMS, latter uses a gateway which actually makes a call & application's responsibility is to connect to the gateway with necessary details.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API called [KooKoo](http://www.kookoo.in/) and they have developed telephony API for automation. You can find details on [Outbound calls here](http://www.kookoo.in/index.php/kookoo-docs/outbound).

You require to send recipient's number and the audio file over the API to play it to the recipient. You need to explore more on the API to understand its capabilities and fulfil your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.                                                                                                                     This is the from KooKoo site. "KooKoo is an interface between your web application and the caller. It takes phone commands from you and executes them on your behalf to the caller". I think, it is still behaving like a 'gateway solution' which I'm not looking for as I mentioned in problem statement.